# Xpath in Python . Getting SyntaxError("invalid predicate")

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

xpathobjects = tree.findall(".//BuildingNodeBase[name = 'Building name']")
```

I am wanting to pull a `BuildingNodeBase` with a child tag name that has value `Building name`.

But Getting:

> SyntaxError("invalid predicate")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The XPath support in ElementTree is limited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax), but your type of expression is supported. It's just that you need to remove the extra spaces around the `=`:

```
.//BuildingNodeBase[name='Building name']
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `lxml` but I guess you can adopt this for your use:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('test.xml')

xpathobjects = tree.xpath(".//BuildingNodeBase[@name = 'Building name']")
```